# jQuery animation on scrolling for elements that has the same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple animation when the `element(s) ($(.box-fadeTop))` reaches **1/3** of the page from the **bottom**. 
And it goes like that:

> if (the element reaches the 1/3 of the page from the bottom when scrolling){
>
> //Do something (CSS for displaying the content)
>
> }

It works well, but the problem is when there's more than one `element` that has the same `class name $(.box-fadeTop);`.

once I reach the **first** `element` it runs the function for **all**.


**How can I set the function depending on each one of the `elements` positions (if there's more than one)?**


Please Open the example in full screen.

```js
var fadeTop = $(".box-fadeTop");
var fadeTopReachBottom = (fadeTop.offset().top - (window.screen.height))+ window.screen.height / 3.33;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var winScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    
    if(winScrollTop >= fadeTopReachBottom){
        $('.box-fadeTop').css({
            transform: 'translate(0, 0)',
            transition: 'all 1s',
            opacity: '1'
        }, 500, 'ease');
    }

});
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    min-height: 3000px;
}

.box-fadeTop {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #888;
    margin: 0 auto;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(50px, -50px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="margin-bottom: 1000px;"></div>

<div class="box-fadeTop"></div>

<div style="margin-bottom: 1000px;"></div>

<div class="box-fadeTop"></div>
```

Comment: you can access the same classes with their indexes like $(".box-fadeTop:eq(0)") for first element and eq(1) or eq(2) respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is targeting them all because $(".box-fadeTop") is an array of all the elements with that class, you only want to target the element that is at 33% from the bottom.

This is a case where JavaScript's IntersectionObserver is the perfect solution. IntersectionObserver watches elements for their position relative to the window (or whatever else you specify) and performs actions based on whether they are intersecting.

```
// Get an array of your "watched" elements
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box-fadeTop');

// Set an observer to watch their position, and run some code if they are at 33% from the bottom of the viewport
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries, self) {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            adjustCss(entry.target)
            // Stop watching them if we don't want to repeat
            self.unobserve(entry.target);
        }
    });
}, { rootMargin: '0px 0px -33% 0px' });

// Tell each individual "box" to be watched
boxes.forEach(box => {
    observer.observe(box);
});

// Function to run on the item that is intersecting
function adjustCss (box) {
    jQuery(box).css({
        transform: 'translate(0, 0)',
        transition: 'all 1s',
        opacity: '1',
        background: 'red'
    }, 500, 'ease');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. It works as expected.

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $(".container .box-fadeTop").each(function(){
      if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
        $($(this)).css({
          transform: 'translate(0, 0)',
            transition: 'all 1s',
            opacity: '1'
        }, 500, 'ease');
      }
    });
});

$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
    var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

    var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    min-height: 3000px;
}

.box-fadeTop {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #888;
    margin: 0 auto;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(50px, -50px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"> 
    <div style="margin-bottom: 1000px;"></div>
    <div class="box-fadeTop"></div>
    <div style="margin-bottom: 1000px;"></div>
    <div class="box-fadeTop"></div>
 </div>
```